# Live profiling of website connected to Oracle DB

Tags: sql-server, oracle, profiling, profiler

I come with from a SQL Server background and i am now using Oracle - I have a website that errors on a particular step, I know it is data related and I want to see what SQL is being run by the website to cause the error.

In SQL Server I would just opened up SQL Server Profiler and profile the site as i clicked through the site.

Is there really no way to do this in Oracle SQL Developer? I've seen this type of question asked a lot and the responses are always with regards to execution plans which is not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you can identify the particular session that is having the issue, you can [trace the session](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof.php) and then process the result offline.  Tracing a session has a measurable impact on performance, however.  While it's probably reasonable to trace one session on a production site, tracing every session is generally going to cause unacceptable performance issues (not to mention generating a ton of trace data to comb through).  Most of the time, you can do something in the worst case to limit the number of sessions that you need to trace (running the app on a different middle tier server or using a different Oracle username) in order to minimize the performance impact.